# Facebook Audience Network showing Ads only when the testing is enabled but not showing ads when the testing option is disabled

Tags: admob, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

I had completed all the process of Facebook Audience Network Implementation for showing ads in my app. I also created a google admob account which was approved by the google team. I also selected Facebook Audience Network as a Ad Source for bidding under the mediation page in google admob account and also added placement id, user token and property id of my facebook business account in google admob's mediation page.

Issue:
I am getting ads when the testing is enabled in facebook audience network testing page. But I am not getting ads when i disabled the testing in facebook audience network  testing page (Link of Facebook Audience Network Testing Page: https://business.facebook.com/pub/testing?business_id=XXXXXXXXXXX)

Ad Type : Native Ads

I am loading ads in my recyclerview with the help of recycler adapter java class

My Adapter Class Code:

```
public class NewRecentPostAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback, AudienceNetworkAds.InitListener{

    private String TAG="NewRecentPostAdapter";
    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    //    private List<RecentPostsResponse.Data> recentList;
    private List<Object> recentList;
    private List<Object> finalList;
    private ArrayList<NativeAd> nativeAd = new ArrayList<>();
    private final int ITEM_TYPE_DATA = 0;
    private final int ITEM_TYPE_AD = 1;
    private final int AD_POSITION = 1;
    private final int AD_POSITION_EVERY_COUNT = 5;
    private NativeAdsManager fbNativeManager;
    private static final String  FB_NATIVE_AD_ID = "XXXXXXXXXX";

    public void initNativeAds(){
        MobileAds.initialize(context, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                Map<String, AdapterStatus> statusMap = initializationStatus.getAdapterStatusMap();
                for (String adapterClass : statusMap.keySet()) {
                    AdapterStatus status = statusMap.get(adapterClass);
                    Log.d("MyApp", String.format(
                            "Adapter name: %s, Description: %s, Latency: %d",
                            adapterClass, status.getDescription(), status.getLatency()));
                }

                // Start loading ads here...
                loadingAds();
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadingAds(){
        fbNativeManager.setListener(new NativeAdsManager.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdsLoaded() {
                Log.i(TAG, "onAdsLoaded!" + fbNativeManager.getUniqueNativeAdCount());
                int count = fbNativeManager.getUniqueNativeAdCount();
                for(int i=0; i< count; i ++) {
                    NativeAd ad = fbNativeManager.nextNativeAd();
                    addNativeAd(i, ad);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onAdError(AdError adError) {
                Log.i(TAG, "AdError: " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }
        });
        Log.i(TAG, "isLoaded: " + fbNativeManager.isLoaded());
        fbNativeManager.loadAds();
    }
    public void addNativeAd(int i, NativeAd ad) {
        if (ad == null) {
            return;
        }
        this.nativeAd.add(i, ad);
        if(recentList.size()>0){
            finalList = (List<Object>) recentList.get(0);
            if(finalList.size()>0){
                this.finalList.add(ad);
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public NewRecentPostAdapter(Activity activity,Context context, List<Object> recentList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.recentList = recentList;
        fbNativeManager = new NativeAdsManager(context, FB_NATIVE_AD_ID,1);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == ITEM_TYPE_AD)
        {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.native_ads, parent, false);
            return new NewRecentPostAdapter.NativeAdViewHolder(v);
        }else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recent_posts_adapter, parent, false);
            return new NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        try {
            finalList = (List<Object>) recentList.get(0);
            Object item1 = finalList.get(position);
            NativeAd ad = null;
            boolean isAd = true;
            try {
                RecentAllPostResponse.Data item = (RecentAllPostResponse.Data) item1;
                isAd=false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isAd = true;
                ad = (NativeAd) item1;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(!isAd) {
                RecentAllPostResponse.Data item = (RecentAllPostResponse.Data) item1;
                Log.v(TAG,"FF="+item);
                if (!item.getTitle().isEmpty()){
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).title.setText(item.getTitle());
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).title.setSelected(true);
                }else {
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).title.setText("NA");
                }
                if (!item.getPrice().isEmpty()){
                    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en", "in"));
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).price.setText(format.format(Integer.parseInt(item.getPrice())));
                }else {
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).price.setText("NA");
                }
                if (!item.getLocation().isEmpty()){
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).location.setText(item.getLocation());
                }else {
                    ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).location.setText("NA");
                }

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getImage())) {
                    if (item.getImage().contains(",")){
                        String[] splitImage = item.getImage().split(",");
                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(ImageURL.POST_IMG_PATH+splitImage[0])
                                .fitCenter()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.amo_logo))
                                .into(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).image);
                    }else {
                        Glide.with(context)
                                .load(ImageURL.POST_IMG_PATH+item.getImage())
                                .fitCenter()
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.amo_logo))
                                .into(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).image);
                    }
                } else {
                    Glide.with(context)
                            .load(R.drawable.picture)
                            .fitCenter()
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.amo_logo))
                            .into(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).image);
                }
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    DetailFragment detailFragment = DetailFragment.newInstance(item.getId(), item.getCatId(), item.getBreedId(), item.getAdId(), item.getPostId(), item.getTitle(), item.getDescription(),
                            item.getLocation(), item.getPostDate(), item.getPostBy(), item.getPostProfile(), item.getPostContact(), item.getGender(), item.getColor(), item.getWeight(),
                            item.getHeight(), item.getAge(), item.getPrice(), item.getImage(), item.getSince(), item.getFollowing(), item.getFollowers(),item.getVideo_url());
                    ft.replace(R.id.container, detailFragment);
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();
                });

                ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).call_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            // reuqest for permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, amo.REQUEST_CALL);
                        } else {
                            boolean loggedIn = Prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
                            if (loggedIn){
                                String contact = item.getPostContact();
                                if (!contact.isEmpty() && !contact.equalsIgnoreCase("NA")){
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + contact));
                                    context.startActivity(intent);
                                }else {
                                    amo.showShortSnack(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).main_lay,"Contact No is Not Valid");
                                }
                            }else {
                                amo.showShortSnack(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).main_lay,context.getResources().getString(R.string.you_reg_proceed));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                ((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).chat_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean loggedIn = Prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
                        if (loggedIn){

                            String postid = item.getPostId();
                            amo.firebase(postid,context,activity);
                        }else {
                            amo.showShortSnack(((NewRecentPostAdapter.PostViewHolder) holder).main_lay,context.getResources().getString(R.string.you_reg_chat));
                        }
                    }
                });

                Log.v(TAG,"FF="+fbNativeManager.isLoaded());
            }else{
                View mNativeView = NativeAdView.render(context, ad, NativeAdView.Type.HEIGHT_300);

                AdView.AdViewLoadConfig loadAdConfig = adView.buildLoadAdConfig()
                        .build();

                adView.loadAd(loadAdConfig);
                ((NewRecentPostAdapter.NativeAdViewHolder) holder).nativeAdContainer.removeAllViews();
                ((NewRecentPostAdapter.NativeAdViewHolder) holder).nativeAdContainer.addView(mNativeView);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 123: {
                for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {
                    String permission = permissions[i];
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                        // user rejected the permission
                        boolean showRationale = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission);
                        if (!showRationale) {
                            // user also CHECKED "never ask again"
                            // you can either enable some fall back,
                            // disable features of your app
                            // or open another dialog explaining
                            // again the permission and directing to
                            // the app setting
                            Log.v("CallOption", "Permission Denied1");
                        } else if (Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE.equals(permission)) {
                            Log.v("CallOption", "Permission Denied2");
                            // user did NOT check "never ask again"
                            // this is a good place to explain the user
                            // why you need the permission and ask if he wants
                            // to accept it (the rationale)
                        }
                    }
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(finalList != null && finalList.size()>0 &&
                finalList.get(position) instanceof NativeAd)
            return ITEM_TYPE_AD;
        else
            return ITEM_TYPE_DATA;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        finalList = (List<Object>) recentList.get(0);
        if(finalList == null)
            return 0;
        return finalList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitialized(AudienceNetworkAds.InitResult initResult) {

    }

    public class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private AppCompatImageView image;
        private ConstraintLayout main_lay;
        private NoboButton call_btn,chat_btn;
        private AppCompatTextView title, price, location;
        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            main_lay = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_lay);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_posts_image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_posts_title);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_posts_price);
            location = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rec_posts_location);
            call_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.call_btn);
            chat_btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chat_btn);
        }
    }

    public static class NativeAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout nativeAdContainer;
        NativeAdViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            nativeAdContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adContainer);
        }
    }
}
```

When using MediationTestSuite, it is showing error i am attaching the screenshot of error here for your reference.

[image]

Help me to solve this issue

Thanks

Comment: Did you wait at least 48 hours? after setting up the ads?

Comment: yes...i am struggling for more than 2 weeks i this issue @Jabbar

Comment: @noor, do you have Facebook installed on your device? You can use this tool to debug the _no_fill_reason_ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/support/troubleshoot/android-debugger/

Comment: @xilosada thanks for your valuable comment. When using this troubleshooter I am getting following message in terminal command - "No Fill error code [1001] No fill"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I resolved this issue by myself. The action what i did was, I replaced the "Facebook Native Ad Source Code" by "Google Native Ad Source Code". Now it is showing facebook ads by bidding process.

1. Complete Bidding Process in FAN (Facebook Audience Network)
2. Create mediation in Google AdMob
3. Connect the google AdMob's mediation with our facebook ad network project using "Placement Id" and "System Access Token"
4. Write source code of google ads in android app thereby the google ads will show the facebook ads by bidding process. ---> Here I used Facebook Ad Source code which we should not do
5. Test the ad by adding device id as test device in google AdMob (It will show test ads only)

Note: Original Ads will be shown only if the app is downloaded from google playstore